# Formula with superscript cut from header in Beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I am using Beamer and have a formula in the subsection headers. It contains a superscript but it is partly cut from the headers. I am using the seagull theme. What can I do to show the superscripted part?

Minimal code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

\begin{document}

\section{Sec. 1}
\subsection{Type $A_{Bq}^{(3)}$}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

(The subscript part also pops up over the allotted space but that doesn't bother me so much.)

[image: portion of output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Nice first question.  I've added an image of the output.  seagull is the color theme, which doesn't affect how the header is cut off.  The culprit is infolines.  But I don't know how to help you beyond that.

Comment: If that suits you, you can try with `\setbeamerfont{headline}{size=\scriptsize}` in the preamble.

Comment: This avoids cropping but enlarges the font a bit...

Comment: @marco sure. But it's the easiest solution I found. Otherwise you can dive in the infolines theme and see how to modify it. Maybe you have to hard code some length…

Answer (score 2):

I found this addition to the preamble that can be helpful:

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=3.05ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=3.05ex,dp=1.5ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsubsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}%
```

The parameter `ht` can be increased to make room above and `dp` to make room below.